# Symfony 5 send meeting in email (MailerInterface)

Tags: symfony, email, calendar, symfony5

I'm using Bolt 4 (based on Symfony 5), and have a custom Controller which has a function that sends an email when a new event is added. I attach to this email an *.ics calendar file. Unfortunately, this file is only seen as an attachement: client such as Gmail or Outlook only sees an email with a file attachement, and not a meeting request.

```php
    use Symfony\Component\Mailer\MailerInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Mime\Email;
    use Symfony\Component\Mime\Address;
    use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail;
    use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;
    use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOExceptionInterface;

    use Bolt\Entity\User;
    use Bolt\Repository\UserRepository;

    private function sendEmail(MailerInterface $mailer, $title, $datetime, $event_id)
    {   
        // Generate the date time string
        setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');
        $date = utf8_encode(strftime("%A %e %B, %Hh%M", strtotime($datetime)));

        $meetingStartTime = strtotime($datetime);
        $meetingEndTime = strtotime($datetime) + 60*60*2;

        // Create the ics file
        $fs = new Filesystem();

        //temporary folder, it has to be writable
        $tmpFolder = $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir') . '/tmp/';

        //the name of your file to attach
        $fileName = 'meeting.ics';

        $icsContent = "
            BEGIN:VCALENDAR
            VERSION:2.0
            CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
            METHOD:REQUEST
            BEGIN:VEVENT
            DTSTART:".date('Ymd\THis', strtotime($meetingStartTime))."
            DTEND:".date('Ymd\THis', strtotime($meetingEndTime))."
            DTSTAMP:".date('Ymd\THis', strtotime($meetingStartTime))."
            ORGANIZER;CN=XYZ:mailto:do-not-reply@example.com
            UID:".rand(5, 1500)."
            ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP= TRUE;CN=Sample:emailaddress@testemail.com
            DESCRIPTION:".$title." requested Phone/Video Meeting Request
            LOCATION: Phone/Video
            SEQUENCE:0
            STATUS:CONFIRMED
            SUMMARY:Meeting summary
            TRANSP:OPAQUE
            END:VEVENT
            END:VCALENDAR"
        ;

        //creation of the file on the server
        $icfFile = $fs->dumpFile($tmpFolder.$fileName, $icsContent);

        // Loop over the users
        $userRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class);
        $users = $userRepository->findAll();
        foreach($users as $user) {
            $email = (new TemplatedEmail())
            ->from(new Address('example@email.com', 'Name'))
            ->to($user->getEmail())
            ->htmlTemplate('email_template.twig')
            ->context([
                'display_name' => $user->getDisplayName(),
                'title' => $title,
                'date' => $date,
                'event_id' => $event_id
            ])
            ->subject($title)
            ->attachFromPath($tmpFolder.$fileName, null, 'text/calendar');

            $mailer->send($email);
        }
        
        //remove the created file
        $fs->remove(array('file', $tmpFolder, $fileName));

    }
```

By comparing an *.eml generated by Outlook, and the *.eml this function generates, I observe this difference:

Email generated by the above code:

```
...
Content-Type: text/calendar; name=meeting.ics
...
```

Email generated by Outlook:

```
...
Content-Type: text/calendar; charset="utf-8"; method=REQUEST
...
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you try to add custom Header https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#message-headers? `->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('Content-type', ''text/calendar; charset="utf-8"; method=REQUEST")`

Comment: I modified the line `->attachFromPath($tmpFolder.$fileName, null, 'text/calendar');` to `->attachFromPath($tmpFolder.$fileName, null, 'text/calendar; charset="utf-8"; method=REQUEST');`, the field is correctly changed in the source of the email, but the client still can't analyze the calendar information.